# how can I increase the width of an image on a HTML page?

Tags: html

I am trying to increase both width and height however only height will increase but not width,I have different values of width but nothing changes I want to span half the width of the page, code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>1st Exercise</title>
</head>



<body>

    <img src="http://salihkalkan.com/wp-content/uploads/demo-image-green-480x318.jpg" alt = "sorry the image cannot load" height="200" width-"2000">
    <h2>FIFA World Cup 2014 News</h2>
    <p>
            The biggest scoreline in the history of the <strong>FIFA World Cup</strong> qualifiers - and indeed in the history of international football - was recorded on 11 April 2001, when Australia beat American Samoa 31-0.
            <br>
            This legendary match also brought global renown for <em>Archie Thompson</em>, whose 13-goal haul set a new world record, which stands to this day, for an individual player in a single international match.
            <br>
            And though the defeat earned American Samoa ignominy, so inspiring has their subsequent recovery been that it is now the subject of an acclaimed documentary, <em>‘Next Goal Wins'</em>, showing across the world.
    </p>


    <h3>Destinations</h3>

</body>
```

Comment: Because you managed to write a typo in `width-"2000"` ?

Comment: ahh what a stupid mistake, I'm still a beginner, thanks for pointing out

Comment: don't use html tags for height and width, instead **use** CSS for that

Comment: yea I'm just required to do this project in HTML, not a homework though just self-learning, thanks for the remark

Answer (score 2):

`width-"2000"` should probably be `width="2000"`?

Comment: Please vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo rather than farm rep from it. This question has no value to future users.

Comment: Done that, was answering when saw the typo

Comment: thanks alot, I have trie to delete it but it wouldn't since it was answered

Comment: Okay, can't see such option, prolly I don't have enough reputation for that? So should I just delete this answer?